# How can I delete all similar Feynman diagrams in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, physics

```
Ext1 = {0, 0}
Ext2 = {8, 0}
Vc1 = {2, 2}
Vc2 = {5, 2}
I1 = Table[i, {i, 1, 3}]
I2 = Table[i - 1, {i, 2, 7}]
Tuples[I1, 2]
int1 = Select[Tuples[I1, 2],
  Last[#] == 3 && First[#] != 2 || Last[#] == 1 && First[#] == 2 &]
Tuples[I2, 2]
int2 = Select[Tuples[I2, 2],
  Last[#] == 3 && First[#] != 5 && First[#] != 1 && First[#] != 2 && First[#] != 3
  || Last[#] == 1 && First[#] == 5 &]
Do[Graphics[{Black, Thick,
    {Line[{Ext1, int1[[i]]}], Line[{Vc1, int1[[1]]}], 
     Line[{Vc1, int1[[2]]}], Line[{Vc1, int1[[3]]}], 
     Line[{Vc2, int2[[1]]}], Line[{Vc2, int2[[2]]}], 
     Line[{Vc2, int2[[3]]}], Line[{Ext2, int2[[j]]}],
     If[i == 1, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j + 2]]}]}],
                 If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j - 2]]}]}]}],
     If[i == 2, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 2]]}]}],
                 If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 2]]}]}]}],
     If[i == 3, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j + 2]]}]}],
                 If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j - 2]]}]}]}]
   }}]
   Graphics[{Black, Thick,
    {Line[{Ext1, int1[[i]]}], Line[{Vc1, int1[[1]]}], 
     Line[{Vc1, int1[[2]]}], Line[{Vc1, int1[[3]]}], 
     Line[{Vc2, int2[[1]]}], Line[{Vc2, int2[[2]]}], 
     Line[{Vc2, int2[[3]]}], Line[{Ext2, int2[[j]]}],
     If[i == 1, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 2]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 2]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}]}],
     If[i == 2, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 2]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 2]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}]}],
     If[i == 3, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 2]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}],
                 If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 2]]}], 
                             Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}]}]
   }}] // Print,
  {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

I have attached the diagram though it's not good looking. need help

[image: Feynman diagram all possible way]

[image: It should be like this diagram]

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question when give not code and no description on how want the diagrams to look.

Comment: I have updated all the relevant things now. I want figure like last pic

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry for inconveniences. Actually, I tried to upload the code but it is so long that it's not uploading. as a new user I 'm not able to make it properly

Comment: Can the downvoteres please calm down a bit! Laboni is a new contributor and needs time  to find her way around here.

Comment: Try to represent each diagram as a `Graph`. Once you have this format, it's easy to tell which graphs are isomorphic with `IsomorphicGraphQ`. After that, maybe the plotting functions for graphs are already good enough for your purposes?

Comment: It's difficult to know what you mean by "similar" diagrams. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170268

Comment: yeah that I saw early  but not getting properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a list of diagrams by using `Table` instead of `Do` with `Print`:

```
A = Table[{{Line[{Ext1, int1[[i]]}], Line[{Vc1, int1[[1]]}], 
            Line[{Vc1, int1[[2]]}], Line[{Vc1, int1[[3]]}], 
            Line[{Vc2, int2[[1]]}], Line[{Vc2, int2[[2]]}], 
            Line[{Vc2, int2[[3]]}], Line[{Ext2, int2[[j]]}], 
      If[i == 1, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j + 2]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j - 2]]}]}]}], 
      If[i == 2, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 2]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 2]]}]}]}], 
      If[i == 3, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j + 2]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j - 2]]}]}]}]},
           {Line[{Ext1, int1[[i]]}], Line[{Vc1, int1[[1]]}],
            Line[{Vc1, int1[[2]]}], Line[{Vc1, int1[[3]]}],
            Line[{Vc2, int2[[1]]}], Line[{Vc2, int2[[2]]}],
            Line[{Vc2, int2[[3]]}], Line[{Ext2, int2[[j]]}], 
      If[i == 1, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 2]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 2]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i + 2]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}]}], 
      If[i == 2, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j + 2]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i + 1]], int2[[j - 2]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}]}], 
      If[i == 3, {If[j == 1, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j + 2]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 2, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 1]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j + 1]]}]}], 
                  If[j == 3, {Line[{int1[[i - 1]], int2[[j - 2]]}], 
                              Line[{int1[[i - 2]], int2[[j - 1]]}]}]}]}},
  {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

The plots from the original post can be recovered from this with

```
Map[Graphics, A, {3}]
```

[image: Feynman diagram all possible way]

Convert a line assembly to a graph: (thanks to @Szabolcs)

```
tograph[X_] := 
  CanonicalGraph[DeleteCases[Flatten[X], Null] /.
    Line[{a_, b_}] -> (a \[UndirectedEdge] b)]
```

Convert all diagrams to graphs:

```
B = Map[tograph, A, {3}]
```

[image]

It looks like they are all isomorphic and thus all diagrams are the same:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[B]]
```

[image]

In case your graph edges are directional, you can use

```
todirectedgraph[X_] :=
  CanonicalGraph[DeleteCases[Flatten[X], Null] /. 
    Line[{a_, b_}] -> (a \[DirectedEdge] b)]
```

which gives directed graphs. They also all turn out to be isomorphic to each other:

```
B = Map[todirectedgraph, A, {3}];
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[B]]
```

[image]

Comment: The efficient way to eliminate isomorphic duplicates is `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, CanonicalGraph]`. This avoids doing all pairwise checks.

Comment: There is one issue though: a Feynman diagram can in general be a multigraph, which is not supported by `IsomorphicGraphQ` or `CanonicalGraph`.  [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has `IGIsomorphicQ`, which *does* support multigraphs.  It also has `IGBlissCanonicalGraph`, which does not. However, it does support vertex-coloured graphs, which in principle can be used to implement multigraph support.

Comment: More generally, a Feynman diagram is an edge-coloured multigraph, which makes things even more complicated, but I think that once we have support for *basic( coloured graphs (IGraph/M does) it can be used to implement full support for the more complicated cases.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Szabolcs. I've added the `CanonicalGraph` function to the `tograph` facility, so that the resulting graphs can be compared directly with `DeleteDuplicates`. Going into details of what Feynman diagrams are and how to represent them: I agree that it's more complex than what @Laboni presents; here I'm merely reacting to her code.

Comment: Thanks @Roman @ Szabolcs

Comment: What is Phi4, @LaboniManna ?

Comment: that is a theory. Ok I got the diagrams.